# SQL: How to get a column's values of all rows as a single value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with SQL Server 2008 R2.

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE step
(
   id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   step_value nvarchar(max) NOT NULL
)
```

Currently there are 197 rows in `step` table. I want to get all values of `step_value` column as a single value with a semi-colon delimiter. How can I do that?

Some sample data:

```
Insert Into step(step_value)
Values ('a'),('b'),('c'),('d'),('<workflow name="DISCIPLINE_LETTER">'), ('   <target>MEETING_INITIAL_MEETING_LETTER</target> ')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use STUFF function

```
select stuff(
 (select '; ' + step_value 
 from step
 for xml path(''), root('MyString'), type
 ).value('/MyString[1]','nvarchar(max)')
, 1, 2, '') as step_values ;
```

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/004e0/4)

Comment: this did not work.

Comment: thanks. but i have characters like < and > in the column and it does not work as it is translating them to &lt; and &gt;. I need the exact values

Comment: @srh Add some sample data in my fiddle

Comment: I have added a sample data to your fiddle

Comment: My sample data cannot be saved in your fiddle. So I have put the sample data in the question above.

Comment: wow this is great. i want to learn this xml path root stuff. can you point me to a great tutorial about this stuff?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 (STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
         FROM step 
         FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '')) AS a
FROM step
```